# PL/SQL cursor problem in procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduling, plsqldeveloper

I have stored procedure.In procedure there are three cursors.I have to run procedure daily in production.I want only two cursors should run daily and the remaining cursor should run only on 1st of every month.So what are the changes should be made to third cursor.Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The cursor itself doesn't actually run. It is your code that uses the cursor. So you can check in code if it is the first day of the month:

```
-- Check if today is first day of the month
if trunc(sysdate, 'MM') = trunc(sysdate) then
  -- Use cursor here
end if;
```

Possibly a better solution is to create two separate procedures and create jobs for each of them. You can specify intervals for the job so one runs daily while the other runs monthly.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [dbms_scheduler](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm)

Comment: This answer is too brusque to be helpful.

Comment: It points him directly to the Oracle documentation, and dbms_scheduler (or some scheduling software) is what is needed here.  Simple, to the point.

Comment: he isn't looking to schedule the procedure, he wants to use one of its cursors conditionally according to the date it runs on.

Comment: @tony, I understand, but when I see "two cursors should run daily ... cursor should run only on 1st of every month" it screams scheduler, esp in prod code.  Its almost inevitable that this timing logic will grow and get more complex.  IT cannot manage changes inside pl/sql, but they can manage schedules.  I guess if I don't have time for a full blown explanation I'll keep my trap shut ;)